# My mom has an iPhone and I have android and I'd like to us my moms hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, shell

Can I use my moms iPhone hot spot for my android

Answer (score 0):

If the iPhone have feature to WLAN Tethering (Wifi Tethering or Hotspot). The answer is yes, you can. I think it will not depend to operating system what you have. Except if the Hotspot have feature to filter any Operating System that can connected to the Hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

It will work normally, just make hotspot (wifi) . And you will be able to connect your phone or your PC, whatever operating system they use.